# Elasticsearch no handler for uri?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I have successfully installed the ELK stack, all is working properly but when i try to access the following link [localhost/logstash-2015-01-01/syslog] either by browser or using curl i get this error message : 
No handler found for uri [/logstash-2015-01-01/syslog] and method [PUT]

I created an index in kibana with the name logstash-*, so the previous link should work, i also have specified a type = syslog in my logstash config.

This is my logstash configuration it is placed in /etc/logstash/conf.d along with 10-syslog.conf,02-filebeat-input.conf and 30-elasticsearch-output.conf those are the defaults i haven't changed them.

My logstash config file :

```
input{
     stdin {}
     file {
      type => syslog
      path => "/var/log/*"
      start_position => beginning
     }
    }

  output {
    stdout {
      codec => rubydebug
    }
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => "localhost"
    }
  }
```

Comment: what is your curl command?

Comment: @ChintanShah25 I tried curl -XPUT with link and data.

Comment: are you providing `_id`? try `curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/logstash-2015-01-01/syslog/1' -d '{"name" : "myname"}'
`

Comment: I tried still the same problem although when i used -XPOST it added the entry, i could view it through localhost:9200/logstash-2015-01-01/syslog/_search, is there a better way to do it ?  ago  
@ChintanShah25

Comment: It works with POST because ES generates new `id` every time whereas for PUT you have to specify one.

Comment: Why are you trying to add a document yourself? Isn't that what you want to do with log stash? So do you want to add a document or do you want to search for documents?

Comment: First: you should specify the type in the elasticsearch output via `document_type => "artikel"`   and to access a saved entry try the `GET` commad